# add cloned gits to personal Gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I own a Gitlab account. In a running repository I have cloned projects from github but on `git add .` they won't be tracked. How do I add cloned projects to my Gitlab account?

```
git branch -vva

* master                c9ef011 [origin/master] te
  remotes/origin/master c9ef011 te
```

Comment: Won't be tracked?  Are you referring to remote tracking branches? Are you trying to push? From where to where?  Or are you trying to import an existing project into Gitlab?

Comment: so I have been cloning locally inside my project gits and I want push to the owned gitlab, but the cloned directories they won't be pushed to gitlab server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you initialize a project in GitLab, you'll see a page like this:

[image]

**The important part is adding the remote**:

`git remote add gitlab git@mygitlaburl:namespace/myproject.git`

You'll need to add your public key by clicking on *Profile Settings* > *SSH Keys* > *Add SSH Key*.

Here are complete instructions: [How To Use the GitLab User Interface To Manage Projects](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-gitlab-user-interface-to-manage-projects)

**UPDATE**:

Your problem is explained here:  [Git repository within Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500305/git-repository-within-git-repository), which links to here: [Nested GIT repo gotchas!](http://boxysystems.com/index.php/nested-git-repo-gotchas/)

Comment: I already have this part. The Project is up and the branch is present in my GitLab. Now In my project I check out gits from github  and those I try to push in my gitlab repository. But they won't be added.

Comment: Why don't you update your question with the output of `git branch -vva`?

Comment: From that output, if you do `git remote -v` you'll see that origin probably refers to your GitHub remote.  You need to do `git remote add gitlab git@mygitlaburl:namespace/myproject.git`.  Then you can do `git push gitlab master`.

Comment: no that one is okay. Probably I do not  explain good the problem. So I can push to gitlab changes but what is not getting pushed are the cloned folders from Github. as example I have project A. Project A has couple of folders what I made myself. Than I clone a project from Github inside Project A let's name it cool_php. Than I want to add to project A and push it to Gitlab.

Comment: That is caused by the way in which git handles nested git repositories.  You may need to learn about git sub-modules or use a build tool to manage external dependencies.  See the answer update.

Answer (score 3):

A convenient option if you have many repos is to mass import:

- go to the directory of a namespace (user or group), e.g. `/home/git/repositories/username`
- get the bare repo: `git clone --bare http://github.com/me/project`. The created repo will end in `.git` and this is required.
- run `bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production`. The GitLab projects will get automatically created on the datbase for you under the user `username`.