# How to migrate gitorious to gitlab repositories

Tags: git, migration, gitlab, repository, gitorious

We use in our company's Gitorious, but I have studied the GitLab lately and have seen much benefit in it.
Recently I managed to climb the gitlab on one of our servers, but now need some help (north) to migrate repositories.

Sorry for my english!

**Edit 1**

We need repositories and commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the best option to move the repos is mass import as I explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26570729/895245

Side note:

For future questions I recommend that you try hard to split the problem into small pieces.

Here, you couldn't you try to eliminate gitorious out of the equation by understanding first how to get the repos out of gitorious and abstracting it out? I bet if you could find the answer yourself this way.

Either that or be very precise about what is special about gitorious that makes the transition difficult.

True, sometimes it is hard to do, but that applies to most questions on SO.

There is even a website encoding that principle: http://sscce.org/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to migrate a lot of repositories, you need to call the GitLab API to create the repos for you so you can copy them over.

Here's a simple PHP script we wrote that should do all the work for you.

https://github.com/sparksi/gitorious-gitlab-migration

Note that GitLab doesn't support repositories inside of projects, so this script uses . to get some semblance of name-spacing.