# How to update git repository that is .gitignored within another repository

Tags: git, repository

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500305/git-repository-within-git-repository) but with a slight difference: the git sub-repository is not a part of the parent. Specifically, the main git repository is [MagicMirror](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror) which allows you to manually import your own custom modules into the program (which are ignored via .gitignore, similar to NPM modules, but manually maintained).

I can download the modules just fine, but calling "git pull" from within their respective repositories calls pull in relation to the main repository and does not update the custom module. I would like to make contributions to the main repository as well as some of the modules.

Is there another way to do this besides symlinks?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you don't need to do anything special, it will treat the sub-repository as though it is its own thing. I was misled to think it was only applying 'pull' on the main repository.